# remote movable workspace access workflow suggestions

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, nx

My users need a solution with these requirements:

- Remote access to multiple Linux-based applications
- Remote access from multiple clients (not simultaneous)
- Application grouping needed such that all the apps associated with one task can be dealt with as a unit
- Ability to "give" applications to another user, preferably retaining grouping

Their current system is running sets of applications under Xvnc, and when they encounter a situation where they need to pass those applications off to another user, they hand off the whole Xvnc session and start a new one.

Right now, this causes problems apparently due to multiple Gnome sessions walking on each others' feet, about which I have another question open.  I should be able to resolve this by getting rid of Gnome, but something really tweaks me about this setup.  Now that I'm thinking about it, I can't really figure out what, but it's still there.

I want to move them into running their apps under xpra (or xmove or freenx or neatx) and then display them on whatever X server they want.  This would give them the ability to move the applications around, they could use whatever X server they want (including Xvnc with Gnome, since they'll only need to run it once), and they could hand applications around.  But I'm concerned that the interface for moving the applications around will be onerous.

Has anyone had any similar situation that they've resolved well?  Or have any ideas regardless of personal experience?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your problems are due to multiple users being logged in at the same time because of your current process requires it or because you have to (business decision).

If all you want is to make it easy to move your sessions from one computer to another, [try this](http://winswitch.org/), that's what it is for.